# How can I change button methods from pack to grid in a class using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm using Tkinter to display plotted points via matplotlib and animation to see updates realtime. Everything worked fine while I used pack to place my labels and buttons, but I wanted to place my buttons in a certain location, so decided to use grid. But now I get an error. I am a neophyte when it comes to Tkinter. I've used grid successfully outside of a class, following an example. But when I tried to change elements from pack to grid in my class, I get an error. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class loginScreen(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Bank App")

        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="filename.ico")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame


            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

...
...

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Login",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(self, column=2, row=2, sticky=(S,E))

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Register",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(self, column=3, row=2, sticky=(S,E))

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.grid(self, column=3, row=3, sticky=(S,E))

...
...

app = loginScreen()
app.mainloop()
```

Here is the error that is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rozelle\Desktop\tkinter_bankAcct.py", line 166, in <module>
app = loginScreen()
 File "C:\Users\Rozelle\Desktop\tkinter_bankAcct.py", line 65, in __init__
frame = F(container, self)
File "C:\Users\Rozelle\Desktop\tkinter_bankAcct.py", line 95, in __init__
button1.grid(self, column=2, row=2, sticky=(S,E))
 File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2057, in grid_configure
+ self._options(cnf, kw))_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-cursor": must be-column, -columnspan, -in, - ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Comment: The column 1 (and also the row 1) is empty. Where do you need to locate the widget _label_ ? You should indicate column and row when calling method _label.grid_. Maybe it explains your problem ?

Comment: Read and act on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  There are multiple problem with the code as posted, including indentation.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly generate the error you say it does. It is filled with errors: indentation errors, undefined variables, etc.

Comment: @BryanOakley it does in fact generate the error! Erroneous indentation can, perhaps, be chalked up to copy/paste. I'm following this code example from an online source, just trying to re-position the buttons and labels. I will attempt what you recommended.

Comment: @suffa: no, it most definitely does not. Try to copy and paste _the code that was posted_ and you will see it has errors, even after fixing the indentation problem. We can't rely on code you don't post, we can only run the code that is in the question. The code in the question most definitely won't run.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought this was obvious, but I will say it now: of course the entire code is not listed. That is why there are ellipses in the code. signifying there is more code. However, that code is not relative to the problem, hence the ellipses.

Comment: @suffa: it's not just the ellipsis that is causing the problem. Your code calls `loginScreen`, `loginScreen` is where the problem is, according to the stack trace, and you don't provide a definition for `loginScreen`. `StartPage` _also_ has the problem, but we shouldn't have to fix half a dozen problems before we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited the code to include loginScreen class

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate moving toward an mcve, this still shows an error.

```
import tkinter as tk

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login")
        button1.grid(self)

root=tk.Tk()
app = StartPage(root, None)
```

Notice the difference in the `.grid` calls?  Never pass the parent in either `pack` or `grid` calls.  Remove `self` and the code works.  Here is a truly minimal but complete and verifiable example.  Using `pack` instead of `grid` gives the same error.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root)
b.grid(root)
```

Comment: OP use `ttk.Button` not `tk.Button` so he can use `self` in `grid` but using `grid(in_=self)`

Comment: @furas: what you say makes  no sense. `self` isn't a valid parameter for `grid` no matter what widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought `self` isn't valid parameter but I found this - http://nullege.com/codes/search/ttk.Button.grid?fulldoc=1 - and there is `in_=master` as valid parameter. (I didn't check if it works)

Comment: @furas: notice that what you link to includes `in_=`. There's a difference between `grid(self, ...)` and `grid(in_=self, ...)`

Comment: @BryanOakley in my first comment I mentioned that OP could use `self` but only with `in_=`. btw: at first I thought `in_` was only available in `ttk` but it seems that it is also available in `tkinter` - https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.0/classtkinter_1_1Grid.html#acce8f7fb7d9efb0d88f3661517f804fc

Comment: @furas: ah, ok. Your first comment is hard to parse. I saw "... so he can use self in `grid`..." and thought you meant it could be the first parameter. My mistake. And yes, `in_` is common to both tkinter and ttk. It's very useful when using tk with tcl, but not needed as much with tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was checking `in_` in code and I could use only the same parent as used in `Button()` (and it seems useless) or a child of that parent (and maybe it could be useful in some way). As yo mentioned, it doesn't seem so much needed in tkinter.

Comment: @furas: you can use `in_` with much more than just the parent. I don't remember the exact rules, but I think it's any ancestor or child of an ancestor. It definitely has to be part of the same root window (ie: you can't have a parent in one Toplevel and try to pack/grid it in another).